# How to declare custom event in userform using vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have userform which collects some user input. Now what I'm trying to do, is to declare some event to throw from userform when OK button is clicked. I'm new to vba so I don't know how to do it. Any code or link to tutorial would be greatly appreciated.

```
Load UserForm1
UserForm1.Show
//here I want to capture UserForm1 OK button's click event and read the data
```

Comment: From Google: http://word.mvps.org/faqs/userforms/CreateAUserForm.htm

Comment: it's not what I'm looking for. I do have a userform, I want to capture it's command button's click event outside of userform.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but you could capture the event within the form code then call a sub or function in a module outside the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment, I don't think what you want to do is possible, but I thought of the following workarounds:

1. If your user input is very simple, like just entering a string, a messagbox could work:

   ```
   Dim sUserInput As Variant

   sUserInput = InputBox("Please enter something useful.", "Title", "Default")

   Debug.Print "sUserInput=" & sUserInput
   ```
2. If you need the form to capture user input, making it modal and then exposing a value through a public method might work.

   In the form:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Private msFormString As String

   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
       msFormString = "Someone clicked on Button 1!"

       '***** Note: if you use Unload Me, the string
       '***** is unloaded with the form...
       Me.Hide
   End Sub

   Public Function GetFormString() As String
       GetFormString = msFormString
   End Function
   ```

   The calling code:

   ```
   Load UserForm1
   Call UserForm1.Show(vbModal)
   Debug.Print "Value from UserForm1: " & UserForm1.GetFormString
   ```

   Note: The function could return an object, class or array if you need to pass more data back.

Answer (score 7):

- In child-form declare event and raise it at the certain moment:

> Public **Event** clickOnChild(ByVal inputText As String)
>
> **RaiseEvent** clickOnChild(Me.TextBox1.Value)

- In a custom class module, worksheet class module or other user form you can catch the event. However you can't catch event in standard module because WithEvents variable are  valid in object module only. To catch your event in e.g. other user form declare WithEvents variable of type childUserForm and
  add event-handler where the event will be catched and handled:

> Private **WithEvents** childForm As childUserForm
>
> Private Sub **childForm_clickOnChild**(ByVal inputText As String)

---

**Complete example:**

*Child user form:*

```
Option Explicit

Public Event clickOnChild(ByVal inputText As String)

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  RaiseEvent clickOnChild(Me.TextBox1.Value)
End Sub
```

*Parent user form:*

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents childForm As childUserForm

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  childForm.Show
End Sub

Private Sub childForm_clickOnChild(ByVal inputText As String)
  MsgBox "Input in child form was: " & inputText
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Set childForm = New childUserForm
End Sub
```